# AWS Quicksight parseJson function not working with redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, business-intelligence, amazon-quicksight

### How to fix parseJson function error in AWS Quicksight?

I have a json column in AWS redshift called discount_codes of type **varchar**. The data looks like this:

`{'code': 'blabla', 'amount': '12.00', 'type': 'percentage'}`

I want to have a seperate column for 'code' in Quicksight. There is a function for this called parseJson. The formular should look like this.

```
parseJson({discount_codes}, "$.code")
```

Unfortunately it is not working and giving me the following error:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: JSON parsing error Details: ----------------------------------------------- error: JSON parsing error code: 8001 context: invalid json object {'code': 'blabla', 'amount': '12.00', 'type': 'percentage'}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I could fix it by myself. The json column had single quotation marks. I replaced them by normal ones. Now the data looks like this:

```
{"code": "blabla", "amount": "12.00", "type": "percentage"}
```

parseJson works now.